# Material transparency with pattern

Tags: materials

I'm looking to create a procedural material similar to the attached, but unsure how to get the transparency with multicoloured dots (I actually need sprinkle shapes, but the transparency, and it being a little cloudy, is the thing I'm struggling with). Any ideas greatly appreciated, as always.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is to use the mask of your image(dots, sprinkles, etc) and use it to switch between a Transparent+Glossy mix and a shader to display the dots(diffuse or actually any shader of your choice)

In my case I used the distance form my Voronoi texture and passed it thorugh a less than to create the mask. Then I simply used it as the factor between thee diffuse and the Transparent+Glossy mix.

Tip: You can change the roughness on the Glossy Node to change how the sharp reflections look. Also change the mix factor to control the transparency.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Akshay2005 I really appreciate this. I think I expected something like this but couldn't figure it out, struggling with the math nodes especially. 

Really appreciate your time here, thanks so much

Stew